Inversion on fermionic operators
Inversion is the transformation defined by
$$\hat{I}\hat{x}\hat{I}^{-1}=-\hat{x},$$
$$\hat{I}\hat{k}\hat{I}^{-1}=-\hat{k},$$
$$\hat{I}i\hat{I}^{-1}=i.$$
It is therefore a unitary operator. Let $\hat{H}$ be a Hamiltonian of free fermions on a lattice with sites labeled by a subindex in the fermionic operators. Unitary operators act on fermionic field as linear applications$$\hat{I}\hat\psi_l\hat{I}^{-1}=\sum_l U_{lm}\hat{\psi}_m.$$
Now, from this fact, one has that
$$\hat{I}\hat{\psi}_k\hat{I}^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_l\hat{I}\hat\psi_l e^{-ikx_l}\hat{I}^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_l\hat{I}\hat\psi_l\hat{I}^{-1}e^{-ikx_l}\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_{lm}U_{lm}\hat\psi_me^{ikx_l}=\frac{1}{\sqrt L}\sum_{l\Delta}U_\Delta\hat{\psi}_{l+\Delta} e^{ikx_l}=\frac{1}{L}\sum_{l\Delta q}U_\Delta \hat\psi_q e^{i(k-q)x_l}e^{-iq\Delta}\\=\sum_\Delta U_\Delta e^{-ik\Delta}\hat{\psi_k}=U_k\hat{\psi}_k.$$
where I used translational invariance and defined $\Delta=l-m$. However, I understand that parity must act inverting the momentum as $\hat{I}\hat\psi_k\hat{I}^{-1}=U\psi_{-k}$. What is the origin of this difference between the conceptual action of this operator and the result of the above calculation?
——————-
EDIT: I am not asking to solve any exercise, I just have noticed a conceptual contradiction between the result that I obtain and the underlying logic of the transformation.

You are using the symbol $i$ to mean multiple different things. What does it mean in your third equation?

Your $U$ goes from having two indices to having a single index. This notation seems pretty unclear...

In the third equation, $i$ is the imaginary unit, meaning that the operator is unitary (i.e. it doesn’t conjugate scalars). When it is used as subscript, it labels a spatial site. I believe this is standard notation and there should be no confusion.

I have made the notation more clear, avoiding the subindex $i$ to denote site labels.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions

The matrix $U_{lm}$ is not translationally invariant, i.e. it is not simply a function of $\Delta = l-m$. This is because you pick an origin when you think of inversions. This is also clear from writing down the form of $U_{lm}$. I think that will resolve the contradiction.

The matrix $_{}$ is not translationally invariant, i.e. it is not simply a function of $Δ=−$. This is because you pick an origin when you think of inversions.
This is also clear from writing down the form of $_{}$. If you imagine you have a one-dimensional chain of rotationally symmetric ($s$) orbitals, we can write $U_{lm} = \delta_{l,-m}$. Then your expression becomes
\begin{align}
\hat{I}\hat{\psi}_k \hat{I}^{-1} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_{lm} U_{lm} \hat{\psi}_m e^{i k x_l} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_{l} \hat{\psi}_{-l} e^{i k x_l} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\sum_{l'} \hat{\psi}_{l'} e^{-i k x_{l'}} \\
&= \hat{\psi}_{-k}
\end{align}
consistent with the usual expectation.
